# Unity: Network Multiplayer

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'm trying to make it so when I click on a server, it becomes selected and I can then run code after clicking on it.

Thank you for whatever assistance you can provide.

```
function OnGUI() {
    if (!Network.isClient && !Network.isServer) {
        if (joining) {
            if (hostData) {
                scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(Rect(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height /
                    6, Screen.width / 1.5, Screen.height / 2), scrollPosition, Rect(0, 0,
                    300, 1000 /* hostData.length * 30 */ ));
                GUI.Label(Rect(30, 0, 100, 20), "Game Name");
                GUI.Label(Rect(350, 0, 100, 20), "Server Info");
                GUI.Label(Rect(590, 0, 100, 20), "Player Count");
                GUI.Label(Rect(700, 0, 100, 20), "Password");
                for (var i: int = 0; i < hostData.length; i++) {

                    GUI.Label(Rect(0, 30 + i * 30, 200, 22), hostData[i].gameName);
                    GUI.Label(Rect(160, 30 + i * 30, 500, 22), hostData[i].comment);
                    GUI.Label(Rect(610, 30 + i * 30, 100, 20), hostData[i].connectedPlayers +
                        " / " + hostData[i].playerLimit);
                    if (hostData[i].passwordProtected) {
                        clientPass = GUI.PasswordField(Rect(680, 30 + i * 30, 100, 25),
                            clientPass, "*" [0], 12);
                    }
                    if (GUI.Button(Rect(800, 30 + i * 30, 100, 25), "Join")) {
                        Network.Connect(hostData[i], clientPass);
                    }
                }
                GUI.EndScrollView();
            }
```

Comment: I read your question on meta, and props for trying to make it clearer. But see, looking at your answer, I see your problem was actually "you don't see the button". How are we supposed to guess that by the current question? :)

Comment: I didn't think it was a display issue at all after the hour or so I spent looking for the problem.

Comment: hmmmm yeah that's a valid point. I'm just saying that if you want to improve on the searchability (therefore validity) of your question, maybe adding something to the effect of what exactly you see (or don't see, as seems to be the case), and what is expected, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was obvious when I changed screen resolutions. Just by changing my screen resolution to 16x9 or 16x10 the buttons showed up.